# C++11 multithreading with class member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I want to use multithreading in C++11 to call a class member function in its own thread. I have been able to get this to work with a global function:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void Alpha(int x)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread alpha_thread(Alpha, 5);
    alpha_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

However, I cannot get it to compile with a class member function:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Beta
{
public:
    void Gamma(int y)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            std::cout << y << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Beta my_beta;
    std::thread gamma_thread(my_beta.Gamma, 5);
    gamma_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The compile error is:

```
no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
 std::thread gamma_thread(my_beta.Gamma, 5);
                                    ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to pass two things: a pointer-to-member, and the object. You cannot call a non-static member function (like `Gamma`) in C++ without an object. The correct syntax would be:

```
std::thread gamma_thread(&Beta::Gamma, // the pointer-to-member
                         my_beta,      // the object, could also be a pointer
                         5);           // the argument
```

You can think of `my_beta` here as being the first argument to `Gamma()`, and `5` as the second.

Comment: If I want to create a `thread` inside the current object constructor, should I change `my_beta`  to `this`?

Comment: @mFeinstein If you're calling your own member function, yeah.

Answer (score 3):

You need to name the function, then pass the object on which to call it as an explicit implicit `this` parameter. :)

```
std::thread gamma_thread(&Beta::Gamma, my_beta, 5);
```

This is a bit of an abstraction leak, granted.

Comment: I chuckled at "explicit implicit `this`"

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems in your program

1. As your compile error says, you need to pass the address of the function `&Beta::Gamma`.
2. You need to pass the object as a parameter considering `this` is an implicit parameter of a member function

### Modified source

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Beta
{
public:
    void Gamma(int y)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            std::cout << y << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Beta my_beta;
    std::thread gamma_thread(&Beta::Gamma, my_beta, 5);
    gamma_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```